# Component Based Android

Tags: user-interface

I need to create a program that can manage memos.

1. create "MyMemoInfoList" program.

   - print out the content in list-form through MyMeMoEditor Program. (memoId, title, date)
   - when you click on edit button after choosing an item, it should bring up detailed contents on MyMemoEditor screen, and after editing the content, the updated content will be reflected on the list.
   - when you choose an item and click on delete button, it will remove the item from the list.
   - if you press the add button, it will bring up the MyMemoEditor screen where you can input contents and save by pressing the save button. Also, it should show up on the list.
2. Create MyMemoEditor Program.

   - new memos will be saved when you register new memos on main screen on the list.
   - when you execute the edit menu, it will update the original memo.
3. Implementation of MyMemoMain/MyMemoInfoList class

   - MyMemoMain class' event should be implemented in anonymous Nested class form.
   - MyMemoInfoList class' event should be implemented by inheriting Listener.

I think the methods that I need to apply is service, BroadcastReceiver, android UI, android UI event, and adapterview.

I am having a difficult time switching through different activities.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

first, your MyMemoInfoList.xml will look like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyMemoInfoList"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/infolist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

================================================================================
next, your editor.xml will look like this(xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyMemoEditor" >

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MemoID" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/memoId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Todo" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="detail" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:lines="3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="date(2014-02-XX)" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="save" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnQuit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="quit"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

=================================================================================
now, let's move onto MyMemoInfoList (activity):

```
package com.example.mymemomain2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyMemoInfoList extends Activity {
    ArrayAdapter<MemoItem> adt = null;
    ListView list = null;
    MemoItem currentItem = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_memo_info_list);

        MemoItemMgr.getInstance().open(this);

        adt = new ArrayAdapter<MemoItem>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                MemoItemMgr.getInstance().list);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.infolist);
        list.setAdapter(adt);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View textview,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) listview.getAdapter();

                currentItem = (MemoItem) adapter.getItem(position);

            }

        });
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        MemoItemMgr.getInstance().save(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, #, 0, "add");
        menu.add(0, #, 0, "delete");
        menu.add(0, #, 0, "edit");
        menu.add(0, #, 0, "save");
        menu.add(0, #, 0, "send");
//# = consecutive integers starting from 1
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == #) {
            add();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == #) {
            delete();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == #) {
            goModify();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == #) {
            MemoItemMgr.getInstance().save(this);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == #) {
            MemoClient client = new MemoClient(MemoItemMgr.getInstance()
                    .getList());
            client.start();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void goHome(View v) {
        finish();

    }

    public void add() {
        Intent i = new Intent(MyMemoInfoList.this, MyMemoEditor.class);
        i.putExtra("mode", 0);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void delete() {
        int position = list.getCheckedItemPosition();
        if (position != -1) {
            MemoItem item = adt.getItem(position);
            adt.remove(item);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please make a selection to delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // if (currentItem != null) {
        // adt.remove(currentItem);
        // }else {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Please make a selection to delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // }
    }

    public void goModify() {
        if (currentItem != null) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MyMemoInfoList.this, MyMemoEditor.class);

            intent.putExtra("mode", 1);
            intent.putExtra("id", currentItem.getMemoId());
            startActivity(intent);
            // finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please make a selection to edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

=======================================================================
now let's take a look at a manager class (class):

```
package com.example.mymemomain2;

import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.StreamCorruptedException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.DuplicateFormatFlagsException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import android.content.Context;

public class MemoItemMgr {
    private static String fileName = "memo.data";
    private static MemoItemMgr instance = new MemoItemMgr();

    public static MemoItemMgr getInstance(){
        return MemoItemMgr.instance;
    }

    int index = 0; 
    ArrayList<MemoItem> list = new ArrayList<MemoItem>();
    private MemoItemMgr(){

    }

    public void open(Context ctx){
        File file = new File(ctx.getFilesDir() , fileName);
        list.clear();
        if(file.exists()){
            ObjectInputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = new ObjectInputStream(ctx.openFileInput(fileName));
                while(true){
                    try{
                    MemoItem item = (MemoItem)in.readObject();
                    add(item);
                    }catch(EOFException e){
                    break;
                    } catch(DuplicateException e){

                    }
                }
            } catch (StreamCorruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }else{
            try {
                add(new MemoItem(1, "Conference call", "Conf. call with international subsidiary", "2014-01-15"));
                add(new MemoItem(2, "Dev Meeting", "weekly updates", "2014-02-15"));
                add(new MemoItem(3, "blind date", "hosting a blind date", "2014-03-15"));
                add(new MemoItem(4, "alumni meeting", "Harvard alumni night", "2014-04-15"));
                add(new MemoItem(5, "colleague meeting", "MS meeting", "2014-05-15"));
                add(new MemoItem(6, "boys' night out", "Yale friends", "2014-06-15"));
            } catch (DuplicateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public void save(Context ctx){
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        try{
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(ctx.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE));
        for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++){
                out.writeObject(list.get(i));
        }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                try{
                    out.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }



    public void add(MemoItem m)throws DuplicateException{
        if(search(m.getMemoId()) == null){
        list.add(m);    
        }else{
            throw new DuplicateException();
        }

    }

//  public void add(String title, String content, String date){
//      MemoItem item = new MemoItem(index++, title, content,date);
//      add(item);
//      
//  }

    public void update(int id, String title, String content, String date){
        MemoItem item = search(id);
        if(item != null){
            item.setTitle(title);
            item.setContent(content);
            item.setDate(date);
        }

    }


    public MemoItem search(int id){
        Iterator<MemoItem> iter = list.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            MemoItem item = iter.next();
            if(id == item.getMemoId()){
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

    public ArrayList<MemoItem> getList(){
        return list;
    }


}
```

================================================================================
next, let's look at MemoItem (class)
set your variables and get getters/setters/constructor/toString

```
package com.example.mymemomain2;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class MemoItem implements Serializable {

    private int memoId;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private String date;

    public MemoItem(){

    }

    public MemoItem(int memoId, String title, String content, String date) {
        super();
        this.setMemoId(memoId);
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setContent(content);
        this.setDate(date);
    }

    public int getMemoId() {
        return memoId;
    }

    public void setMemoId(int memoId) {
        this.memoId = memoId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "ID:" + getMemoId() + ","
                + getTitle() + ":" +getDate();
    }





}
```

==================================================================================
Now, lets move onto MyMemoEditor (activity):

```
package com.example.mymemomain2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyMemoEditor extends Activity {

    int mode = 0;
    int id = 0;

    EditText edt1=null;
    EditText edt2=null;
    EditText edt3=null;
    EditText edt4=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_memo_editor);

        edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.memoId);
        edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        edt3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.content);
        edt4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mode = intent.getIntExtra("mode", 0);
        if (mode == 1) {
            id = intent.getIntExtra("id", -1);  //write random number that doesn't make any sense
            if(id!= -1){
                MemoItem item = MemoItemMgr.getInstance().search(id);
                edt1.setText(item.getMemoId() + "");
                edt1.setEnabled(false); //this will prevent you from editing
                edt2.setText(item.getTitle());
                edt3.setText(item.getContent());
                edt4.setText(item.getDate());
            }
        }

        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        Button btnQuit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnQuit);

        btnQuit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                quit(v);
            }
        });

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                save(v);
            }
        });

    }

    public void save(View v) {

        int memoId = Integer.parseInt(edt1.getText().toString());

        String title = edt2.getText().toString();

        String content = edt3.getText().toString();

        String date = edt4.getText().toString();

        if (mode == 0) {
            try {
                MemoItemMgr.getInstance().add(new MemoItem(memoId, title, content, date));
                finish();
            } catch (DuplicateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Duplicative ID. Please write a different ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                edt1.setText("");
                edt1.requestFocus();
            }
        } else if (mode == 1) {
            MemoItemMgr.getInstance().update(id, title, content, date);
            finish();
        }



    }

    public void quit(View v) {
        finish();
    }

}
```

===================================================================
Now let's take a look at client (class):

```
package com.example.mymemomain2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MemoClient extends Thread {


    ArrayList list = null;
    public MemoClient(ArrayList list){
        this.list = list;
    }




    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket("70.12.109.92", 7777);
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                objOut.writeObject(list.get(i));
        } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                objOut.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }

}
```

=====================================================================================
Lastly, make a new project(java) and make a server (class):

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import com.example.mymemomain2.MemoItem;

public class MemoServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(7777);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("waiting...");
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            while (true) {
                try {
                    MemoItem item = (MemoItem) objIn.readObject();
                    System.out.println(item);
                } catch (EOFException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*******************************************************************************    
********************Just FYI, here is another example.**************************
*******************************************************************************
```

========================================================================

Fist, lets edit the xml files.

=========================================================================

here is the main xml for the main page
(Make sure you change your layout format according to the problem given)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".NotePadActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

====================================================================================
Next, lets move onto note edit xml file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".NoteEditActivity" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ID" />
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edtId"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title" />
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edtTitle"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Content" />
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edtContent"
        />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            />

         <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

===============================================================================

Now, lets work on the main activity (NotePadActivity)

```
package com.example.notepad;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NotePadActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int MODE_ADD = 0;
    public static final int MODE_EDIT = 1;

    public static final int MENU_ADD = 1;
    public static final int MENU_EDIT = 2;
    public static final int MENU_DELETE = 3;
    public static final int MENU_SEND = 4;
    public static final int MENU_EXIT = 5;

    ListView listview = null;
    ArrayAdapter<Note> adt = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        NoteManager.getInstance().open(this);

        adt = new ArrayAdapter<Note>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, NoteManager
                        .getInstance().getList());
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview.setAdapter(adt);
        listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, MENU_ADD, 0, "Add");
        menu.add(0, MENU_EDIT, 0, "Edit");
        menu.add(0, MENU_DELETE, 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(0, MENU_SEND, 0, "Send");
        menu.add(0, MENU_EXIT, 0, "Exit");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == MENU_ADD) {
            add();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == MENU_EDIT) {
            edit();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == MENU_DELETE) {
            delete();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == MENU_SEND) {
            send();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == MENU_EXIT) {
            exit();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        NoteManager.getInstance().close(this);
    }

    private void exit() {
        finish();
    }

    private void send() {
        NoteClient client = new NoteClient(NoteManager.getInstance().getList());
        client.start();

    }

    private void delete() {
        int position = listview.getCheckedItemPosition();
        if (position != -1) {
            Note note = adt.getItem(position);
            adt.remove(note);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select the one that you want to delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private void edit() {
        int position = listview.getCheckedItemPosition();
        if (position != -1) {
            Note note = adt.getItem(position);

            int id = note.getId();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("mode", MODE_EDIT);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select the one that you want to edit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void add() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("mode", MODE_ADD);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

=========================================================================================

Now let's create a Note (class):

```
package com.example.notepad;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Note implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String content;



    public Note(int id, String title, String content) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + id + "]" + title;
    }




}
```

==================================================================================
Next class that we will create is NoteManager(class):

```
package com.example.notepad;

import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;

public class NoteManager {
    // need to use singleton

    private static NoteManager instance = new NoteManager();

    public static NoteManager getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    private String fileName = "note.ser";
    private ArrayList<Note> list = new ArrayList<Note>();

    private NoteManager(){

    }

    public void open(Context ctx){
        File file = new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), fileName);
        if(file.exists()){

                    //use FileStream to read the file and add by using add()
            ObjectInputStream objIn = null;
            try {
                FileInputStream fin = ctx.openFileInput(fileName);
                objIn = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
                while(true){
                    try{
                    Note note = (Note)objIn.readObject();
                    add(note);
                    }catch(EOFException e){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                try {
                    objIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }else{
            //force add the content by using add()
            try {
                add(new Note(123, "Ethical quotes", "Content blah blah"));
                add(new Note(124, "Todo", "bla she bla she"));
                add(new Note(1, "Grocery", "hohoho"));
                add(new Note(13, "Bus route", "hong hong hong"));

            } catch (DuplicateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void close(Context ctx){
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = null;

        try {
            FileOutputStream fin = ctx.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fin);

            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                Note note = list.get(i);
                objOut.writeObject(note);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                objOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void add(Note note) throws DuplicateException{
        //repetition check
        if(search(note.getId()) == null){
        list.add(note);
        }else{
            throw new DuplicateException();
        }
    }

    public Note search(int id){
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Note note = list.get(i);
            if(id == note.getId()){
                return note;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<Note> getList(){
        return list;

    }

    public void update(int id, String title, String content){
        Note note = search(id);
        note.setTitle(title);
        note.setContent(content);
    }

    public boolean remove(int id){
        Note note = search(id);
        return list.remove(note);
    }





}
```

===================================================================================

Now, we make another activity (NoteEditActivity):

```
package com.example.notepad;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NoteEditActivity extends Activity {
    int mode = 0;

    EditText edtId;
    EditText edtTitle;
    EditText edtContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_edit);

        edtId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtId);
        edtTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTitle);
        edtContent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtContent);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mode = intent.getIntExtra("mode", NotePadActivity.MODE_ADD);
        if (mode == NotePadActivity.MODE_EDIT) {
            edtId.setEnabled(false);
            int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", -1);
            Note note = NoteManager.getInstance().search(id);
            edtId.setText(id + "");
            edtTitle.setText(note.getTitle());
            edtContent.setText(note.getContent());
        }

        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        Button btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(edtId.getText().toString());
                String title = edtTitle.getText().toString();
                String content = edtContent.getText().toString();

                if (mode == NotePadActivity.MODE_ADD) {
                    try {
                        NoteManager.getInstance().add(
                                new Note(id, title, content));
                        finish();
                    } catch (DuplicateException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(NoteEditActivity.this,
                                "Duplicate ID, please use different ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    }
                } else if (mode == NotePadActivity.MODE_EDIT) {
                    NoteManager.getInstance().update(id, title, content);
                    finish();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.note_edit, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

====================================================================================
Lastly we create client/server:
First, let's create a server (new java project + class in it):
also, don't forget to change your permission settings from the manifest file.

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class NoteServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8888);
        System.out.println("waiting....");
        while(true){
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while(true){
                try{
//                  Note note = in.readObject();
                    String note = (String)in.readObject(); //use this if you don't remember.
                    System.out.println(note);

                }catch(EOFException e){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

=============================================================================
Finally, we will make our new client class:

```
package com.example.notepad;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NoteClient extends Thread {

    ArrayList<Note> list = null;
    public NoteClient(ArrayList<Note> list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        Socket socket = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        try{
            socket = new Socket("70.12.109.92", 8888);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Note note = list.get(i);
//              out.writeObject(note);
                out.writeObject(note.toString());               //if used toString in Server

            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```